# Why this computer doesn't have a VPN client gateway attached to it?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am trying to understand how **Remote Access VPNs** works, I have found the following diagram which shows an example of this type of VPN architecture (the diagram is from this [article](https://www.checkpoint.com/smb/help/utm1/8.0/1197.htm)):

[image]

Now I suppose that when the *Home Worker* computer sends a packet and this packet reaches *Home gateway [VPN Client]*, the packet will be encrypted and encapsulated and then sent to *Office Gateway [VPN Server]*.

But what I don't understand is why the *Mobile Worker* computer doesn't have a VPN client gateway attached to it, is it because it have a VPN client software installed on it? or is this diagram simply showing an example of a computer that is using VPN and another computer that is not using VPN (the [article](https://www.checkpoint.com/smb/help/utm1/8.0/1197.htm) doesn't say anything about this)?

Comment: I would suppose that the mobile worker is both a gateway and a client in this diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The two previous answers are incorrect. As a former employee of the corporation who created this diagram, I'd be happy to explain what it is depicting. This diagram represents two different types of VPN: site-to-site vs. client-to-site. The broadband connection is using a VPN gateway that establishes a site-to-site (always up) VPN which means that any and all traffic exiting that network is traversing an encrypted tunnel to the corporate main location, where all VPN traffic is decrypted on their gateway.

The Mobile Worker has VPN client software installed on their machine, and traffic from that machine alone is being encrypted between that machine and the corporate gateway. It's a client-to-site VPN. The client can have a split tunnel that determines what traffic to route out to the Internet (unencrypted) and what traffic to route through the VPN to the corporate location.

Answer (score 0):

The "Mobile worker" is marked as using *dial-up*. That is, it doesn't connect to the Internet at all – it is dialling *directly* into the company's own systems (using an oldschool [modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem)), without needing any additional clients.

While rare nowadays, this used to be a very common way of accessing the workplace network from anywhere that had a phone line, back when public Wi-Fi was a rarity – meanwhile, many laptops had a built-in modem and a phone jack.

(In fact, some VPN softwares were *modelled after* dial-in access, just replacing "Phone number" fields with "Server IP address" ones. For example, Windows Server RRAS shows virtual VPN "ports" the same way it'd show modem dial-in ports, and PPTP even uses the exact same PPP protocol tunnelled over TCP/IP instead of phone line.)

---

Meanwhile, the "Home worker" has a 'broadband' connection which is always-on. Therefore it is more convenient to reach the company's systems over the existing Internet connection, but on the other hand it needs an additional tool – the VPN client.

---

That said, I'm not sure why the "Home worker's" VPN client is shown to be part of the home gateway. (It would be normal for site-to-site VPNs between dedicated routers, but... it's a bit unusual for personal remote access.)

Answer (score 0):

This diagram is pretty bad, because it makes it seem like the "Home Gateway" has anything to do with the VPN Client.

- The VPN client is typically *software* that runs on a laptop, desktop, or phone.

  - It is possible to run certain types of VPN clients on a home router or gateway, and also on enterprise routers or gateway devices.  Obviously you want laptops to have a software client installed on them.
- This software client adds a virtual network adapter to the device.  Applications use this not realizing it's not a real network adapter.
- The VPN client software takes incoming traffic from that virtual network adapter, encrypts it, and then sends it to a central VPN server.
- The central VPN server decrypts it and sends it on to its intended destination.  VPN servers can be standard PCs or servers, or the functionality can be built into a enterprise grade router.

  - You could be crazy and run certain types of VPN servers, such as OpenVPN, right on your laptop.